# If record exists INSERT from the next row (Sql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have imported a `.csv` file into my database table.

It has three columns, for example

```
(numbers, first_name, last_name)
```

`numbers` column's rows start from 1 to 200.

Now, I want to import a new `.csv` file into that same table. I will do it every day. Each time rows start from 1 to some number.

New `.csv` file's "numbers" values start at 1 and go to 500.

When I import the new `.csv` file, it needs to continue from 201. It shouldn't update or delete old rows. Vice versa, it needs to continue rows from 201.

How can I do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you never want to use the value provided from the CSV file, define `numbers` as an `identity` column:

```
create table the_table
(
  numbers integer not null generated always as identity,
  first_name text, 
  last_name text
);
```

Then when you import the CSV, only import `first_name` and `last_name`. How you do that, depends on the tool you use to import the file. Unfortunately the built-in `copy` command or psql's `\copy` can import only some columns of a file. You an also apply this to an existing table that already contains data.

If you can't import only some columns, you can create a sequence that will always be used through a trigger. This will effectively ignore any value provided for the numbers column:

```
create sequence numbers_seq
     start with 201; --<< or whatever you need depend

create table the_table
(
  numbers integer not null,
  first_name text, 
  last_name text
);

create function set_number() 
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  new.numbers := nextval('stuff.numbers_seq');
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

create trigger populate_numbers_trigger
  before insert on the_table
  for each row 
  execute procedure set_number();
```

During an import (*any* INSERT actually) the values will always be taken from the sequence, regardless of what was specified in the INSERT statement. This works independently of any tool. The trigger however is slightly slower than the `identity` column.